# Calculate text field using python script and keeping preceding zeroes

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to calculate records in a text field to "01", keeping the preceding zero in tact using python script in ArcGis.

I can do this easily using the field calculator in ArcMap or the calculate field gp tool. But the script results in "1" instead of "01" and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Table1","Field1","01","PYTHON","#")
```

Comment: Please do not include thanks in your posts here. It is considered unnecessary chit chat as per the [Tour] and [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your number `"01"` into a second set of quotes `"'01'"` (double-quote then single-quote or the other way around)

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Table1","Field1","'01'","PYTHON","#")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the .zfill() function somewhere in your code. Input the length you are needing in the parentheses, 2 in your case. This will pad the text field with 0s

Comment: Could you please include an example of how to use `.zfill()`?

Comment: When i need to pad a field with 0's, say a ZIP code that is 00601, but displaying as 601. !ZIP!.zfill(5) would field calculate 2 0's in front, turning it into 00601